# Android Project as a library - sqllite database issue

Tags: android, project

I have a little quiz project that am adding as a library to a main project, everything seems to work except when it comes to connecting to the sqlite database, I get the following error:

```
10-16 22:10:47.942: ERROR/Cursor(5868): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/org.ttrssreader/databases/ttrss.db, table = null, query = SELECT id,title,unread FROM categories WHERE id>0 ORDER BY UPPER(title) ASC
10-16 22:10:47.942: ERROR/Cursor(5868): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

anyhelp is greatly appreciated...

Comment: I've added a general answer for these errors, but if you are still stuck then please provide a full stack trace as well as the section of your code where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't cleaning up your cursors or open database. Every time that you perform a database operation that returns a cursor object, you must call close() on the cursor when you are done reading data from it. Also, when you are done with the database itself, you should call close on the database.

This can also happen if you create multiple instances of SQLiteOpenHelper for the same database. You should just instantiate a SQLiteOpenHelper subclass once and keep a reference to it for all further DB operations.